# The "Add Comment" button is broken in the flags queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Noticed it in the flags queue here on Meta, which is using the new **big buttons** everywhere.

> [image: Broken button]

Comment: There is also a problem I noticed with the sidebar text overriding other things also.  Also, it affects this very comment.  I just wasn't sure if it was because of my zoom level or something.

Comment: Are you not at stock zoom level? With the exception of mobile browsers, Zoom tends to be a nightmare on any sort of layout

Comment: I never use any sort of zoom. It doesn't do this for that button anywhere else on the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New padding for buttons partially conflicts with existing styles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161149/new-padding-for-buttons-partially-conflicts-with-existing-styles). I know that that was asked later, but it has more details..

Comment: Why don't we need a button to add a commen `T`?

Comment: Community must like you. She bumped that old post that should be resolved now!

Comment: Assuming this was fixed at some point, since I don't see it now.

Comment: @Shog9: Oh, yeah, well, you have those fancy black buttons now... Haven't noticed a problem with them.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a little different on my screen on this question in Firefox.  I hit the 'reset' in the View->Zoom menu first.

[image: Bad Comment Button]

Comment: So this appears everywhere for you? Interesting... I can't reproduce that in any browser. My button looks fine everywhere except the flags queue.