# New padding for buttons partially conflicts with existing styles

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The “Add Comment” button is broken in the flags queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161001/the-add-comment-button-is-broken-in-the-flags-queue)

It seems like there was a recent addition to the site CSS:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0.3em 0.6em;
}
```

This finally brings some very welcome padding to buttons in browsers that don't add padding to all `input`s per default (like Chrome). So, yay.

Sadly, some of the buttons on our sites also have fixed widths. In combination with the above padding rule, that can lead to unpleasant results:

[image]

This is the result of:

```
.comment-form > form input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Which sites? I'm not seeing it on any I've visited today.

Comment: @ChrisF: [su] definitly and from what I can tell, [metase] has it as well. Seems like the **Add Comment** button is only problematic when it appears through the mod tools though.

Comment: I only ask as your background is black - so do you have any custom css installed?

Comment: @ChrisF: http://stackapps.com/questions/3724/super-user-dark-theme

Comment: Already [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161001/the-add-comment-button-is-broken-in-the-flags-queue), but this has more details

Comment: @Mat so you think it's better to close the other (older) as dupe of this one? Doesn't feel right to keep both open.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yeah, I asked on chat before posting here. Seemed like my own CSS was not to blame.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I don't really know (and I don't think this is really important). I just put the link there so that _someone else_ could figure out the best thing to do :)

Comment: what browser/ver are you using?

Comment: @Jin: Google Chrome

Comment: @OliverSalzburg if you use Inspector to remove width: 100px does it solve the problem? btw I can't repro this on Chrome.

Comment: @Jin: Yes, that resolves the issue. The issue only seems to appear in the flag queue as indicated by the [other report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161001/the-add-comment-button-is-broken-in-the-flags-queue).

Comment: Dangit, now we have closes in both directions. (And adding this comment I get the messed up button, it's not just the mods flag queue.)